# Background style not updating on scroll event. (non-jQuery)

Tags: javascript

```
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];

window.onscroll = function(){
    var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined,
        isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || '') === 'CSS1Compat'),
        top = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop,
        calc = Math.abs(1 - (top + 200) / 200);

    if(calc <= '1'){
        nav.style.background = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.'+calc+')';

        console.log('rgba(0,0,0,0.'+calc+')');
    }
}
```

If I console it. The function works well. But when I check the element. Nothing happens with it.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/238rjf9a/1/

Scroll it and you can see what I am talking about.

Note: I don't use jQuery for this project.

Thanks for those who will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an surplus **0.** in your style.

Try this: `rgba(0,0,0,'+calc+')`

Comment: Worked like charm mate. Thanks so much. I'll accept your answer in 10mins. I don't know why stackoverflow needs me to wait 10mins.

Answer (score 0):

Your **calc** already has the leading **0**. Please change your code to:

```
if(calc <= '1'){
    nav.style.background = 'rgba(0,0,0,'+calc+')';

    scr.innerHTML = 'Srolled = rgba(0,0,0,'+calc+')';
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/238rjf9a/2/